# Alternatives to SQLite for Java that supports multi-user write

Tags: java, sqlite

Does anyone know of a sqlite alternative for Java that would support multiple write(s) at the same time?

I'm aware of the option of checking to see if the database is available and pause the attempt to write until it can actually write. But still I'm looking for alternatives where I can really do concurrent writes.

**Update (further explanation):**
I'm setting up a system where there will be multiple users keying in a single database so I would naturally like the idea of being able to work non-stop instead of having to pause to wait for the database to be available for writing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "at the same time?" Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: you mean embedded and multiconnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) - it's feature rich embeddable file-based DB.